# Password is not working to access Encrypted Disk Image storing hundreds of files on my Mac

Tags: mac, encryption, passwords

About a week and a half ago I followed instructions from the following article from HowToGeek and everything was working fine:

https://www.howtogeek.com/183826/how-to-create-an-encrypted-file-container-disk-image-on-a-mac/

I created three separate 'containers'. One of was 10GB, another one was 5GB, and the first one was just the smaller size that they offered me when I was first experimenting with this process.

Everything worked.  I set a unique, complicated password which I also wrote down in a secret place.   I put all of my most important files in these containers.   I was able to access them each time that I entered the password.  All of the files showed up without a problem.

Now, a few days later, my password is being rejected.  First of all, remember it clearly.  Second of all, I also wrote it down as I already mentioned.  Nobody has had access to my laptop which is a Macbook Air. 
It is macOSMojave Version 10.14.3.

I do believe I upgraded it after setting up this encryption, but that does not seem like it should have anything to do with it.  I was using High Sierra up until a few days ago (I believe the latest version).

I know nothing about how computers work.  I have tremendously important files stored in all of these containers, and I was going to back them up to Time Machine next, now that they are encrypted.

What could possibly be causing the password not to work?  There is zero chance I am entering the wrong password, and it is being rejected on all three dmg images.   Thank you for any input! Again, the files that I have stored are incredibly important.  (Some of them have been saved to external drives, but many of them have not).

Comment: Twisty Impersonator - Thank you! I was trying to figure out how to use a plain text editor, and yet decided first to just try again typing my password in manually.  It worked, in all three cases!   It's hard to believe I could actually have typed it in incorrectly 7+ times in a row (when I never seemed to have a problem before), but apparently that is what happened.   Your suggestion really helped.  I wonder if there could be something wrong with my keyboard, or maybe it's just because there are various letters requiring the shift button.

Comment: Very strange.  Especially because I though I was being extremely meticulous after it did not work the first three times.  In any case, what a relief.  Best regards!

Comment: I've seen it happened a hundred times where users entering a complex password when they can't see the characters make repeated mistakes. Don't feel bad, computers are extremely unforgiving when it comes to requiring your exact password. But that's a good thing. That's what keeps the bad guys out.

Comment: It appears that you have been using an unregistered account to create new posts which will limit your ability to interact with this community. Unregistered accounts only work from the original browser that you asked the question from and can be lost if you clear cookies or change browsers. If you wish to use multiple machines or browsers then you will need to register an account and request your accounts are merged using the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible You're simply entering your password incorrectly. Try typing it into a plain text editor, then copy it from there into the password prompt field. This will ensure you've typed the password correctly.

It's not uncommon to make a mistake when entering a complex password. Sometimes even trying multiple times doesn't work because one may be making the same mistake repeatedly, but due to the fact you can't see the entered characters do the password masking, you're not aware of the error.